# UTFGrid grid map generated by TileMill v0.10.1 looks off from the actual map

Tags: tilemill, utfgrid

I have been trying to create `UTFGrid` from shapefiles using `TileMill` v0.10.1. For some reason the grid map it generated looks like it is stretched from the original map.
For Example:

This is the Original Tile:

[image]

What `TileMill` generated:

[image]

The top half of the image is correct, however, the bottom half of the character map becomes all `'?'` and the layout still follows the original image but stretch to the right.

This only happens when the `UTFGrid` is exported in `mbtiles`, when using `UTFGrid` interactivity inside `TileMill`'s GUI, it works perfectly...

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, the issue is resolved.

It wasn't an issue with TileMill, but the way I was converting MbTile's binary data to ASCII character map is wrong.

ASCII only support up to 128 characters thus any binary above 128 got converted incorrectly. I convert the binary data into UTF-8 and it works perfectly.